# Mutagen : how to extract album art properties?

Tags: python, image, id3, mutagen

I am trying to get properties (just width & heigth so far, but probably more later) of an album art picture from an mp3 file using python 3.7.1 and mutagen 1.42, but nothing seems to work so far. I am yet able to extract some other information correctly

The doc is telling about [APIC](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3_frames.html#mutagen.id3.APIC), but trying to display all tags doesn't show anything related to any picture (and my mp3 test files *does* have album pictures) :

```
import os,sys
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3

song_path = os.path.join(sys.argv[1]) # With sys.argv[1] the path to a mp3 file containing a picture
track = MP3(song_path, ID3=EasyID3)
pprint(track.get('title')[0] + ' ' + str(track.info.length) + 's, ' + str(int(track.info.bitrate / 1000)) + 'kbps')
print(track.keys())
```

The result, using a file of mine :

```
> Exponential Tears 208.0s, 205kbps
> ['album', 'copyright', 'encodedby', 'length', 'title', 'artist', 'albumartist', 'tracknumber', 'genre', 'date', 'originaldate']
```

(This mp3 file does have an embedded picture, that I can see with any music software I use.)

I have found a lot of different ways of handling this with mutagen, but some seems outdated, others just doesn't work, I don't understand what I am missing here.

Any help here would be gladly appreciated

Comment: Can you include an [mcve] showing complete functional code?

Comment: Done in the edits

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, i eventually figured it out : the EasyID3 module only handles most common tags, and it does not includes picture data (APIC). For that, you need to use the [ID3](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3.html) module, which is way more complex to understand. Then, look for the [*APIC:*](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3_frames.html#mutagen.id3.APIC) key, which stores the picture as a byte string.

Here is a little exemple, using PIL to deal with pictures :

```
import os,sys
from io import BytesIO
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3
from PIL import Image

song_path = os.path.join(sys.argv[1])
track = MP3(song_path)
tags = ID3(song_path)
print("ID3 tags included in this song ------------------")
print(tags.pprint())
print("-------------------------------------------------")
pict = tags.get("APIC:").data
im = Image.open(BytesIO(pict))
print('Picture size : ' + str(im.size))
```

Hope it helps, good luck ! ;)

Comment: I think this needs a bit of updating as `getall('APIC')[0]` seems to work for me.