# How to get album image from a music file using Mutagen and python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mutagen

I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54757751/mutagen-how-to-extract-album-art-properties) but it doesn't work. 
Here's my code:

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3
music = ID3('music.mp3')
music.get('APIC:').data
```

I get following error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'. I also tried to find out the field name using ID3('music.mp3'). There's no field name called APIC:, instead there's a field called APIC:thumbnail .

Comment: Without seeing your code, we're just guessing at the problem.

Comment: @JohnGordon i edited the question. Please check it once again

Comment: `music.get('APIC:')` is returning `None`.  That's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the solution. remember to add [0] otherwise you'll get error saying that it has no attribute called data.

```
from mutagen.id3 import ID3
music = ID3('music.mp3')    
music.getall("APIC")[0].data
```

Comment: Also you're using `.getall()` instead of `.get()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes. The answer i linked in my question suggests using .get() It didn't work for me but getall() did.