# Python 3.8 Mutagen wont read GEOB tag

Tags: python, mp3, pydev, id3, mutagen

I'm using PyDev with Eclipse. Mutagen installed through Anaconda.

I have experience in C, but decided to give Python a shot. Not sure why this isn't working, and there's not a lot of examples for Mutagen. This is a simple mp3 that I'm trying to read a tag from. I checked the Mutagen spec and the GEOB class does exist. But I dont see what I'm missing.

Here is my python file:

```
import mutagen

from mutagen.id3 import ID3

audio = ID3("Test.mp3") #path: path to file

titleData = audio.get('TIT2')
print(titleData)

tagData = audio.get('GEOB')  # returns None as a default
print(tagData)
    
 
print("Done!")
```

Here is the output:

```
Stupid Song
None
Done!
```

I'm using a file Test.mp3 as my test case. And if I open with a hex editor, I see there is in fact a GEOB tag:
[image: Screenshot of 010 Editor]

So I would expect to see an output other than 'None'. Any help is appreciated!

Update:
Added the lines:

```
printall = audio.pprint()
print(printall)
```

and got the output:

```
GEOB=[unrepresentable data]
GEOB=[unrepresentable data]
GEOB=[unrepresentable data]
GEOB=[unrepresentable data]
GEOB=[unrepresentable data]
GEOB=[unrepresentable data]
GEOB=[unrepresentable data]
TBPM=142
TCON=Other
TIT2=Stupid Song
TKEY=E
TSSE=Lavf58.20.100
TXXX=SERATO_PLAYCOUNT=0
```

So am I just using the audio.get function incorrectly? I would like to be able to get all that [unrepresentable data] as binary, or hex.

Comment: Does `audio.pprint()` even list the GEOB frame? (Terms: "tag" is the whole thing; "frame" is i.e. "TIT2" and "GEOB")

Comment: Updated my post. GEOB frames are listed. Not sure why I'm not getting data from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the mutagen [manual](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3.html#mutagen.id3.ID3Tags.getall) to get all the frames with a given identifier, the method call is "getall" not "get". The following method returns the song title and all GEOB frames.

```
def get_tags_mutagen(filepath):
    audio = ID3(filepath) #path: path to file
    
    titleData = audio.getall('TIT2')
    print("Song Title: ", titleData)

    tagData = audio.getall('GEOB')  # returns None as a default
    for i in tagData:
        print(i)

    return tagData
```

Answer (score 0):

I neither know mutagen nor Python, but as per the manual any **text frame** (i.e. your [`TIT2`](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3_frames.html#mutagen.id3.TIT2)) is based on the [mutagen.id3.TextFrame](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3_frames.html#mutagen.id3.TextFrame) class, having a `.text` attribute. So when you issue:

```
titleData = audio.get('TIT2')
```

...you actually do:

```
titleData = audio.get('TIT2').text
```

With that in mind now look at [mutagen.id3.GEOB](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3_frames.html#mutagen.id3.GEOB): it doesn't have any such attribute. It's up to you choose what you want to get - maybe `.desc`?

There are also other **frames** that also have no primary text - most prominently [`APIC`](https://mutagen.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/id3_frames.html#mutagen.id3.APIC) ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54773705/4299358)), which you might also easily encounter/want to process. **Text frames** are the most simple type, but by far not the only ones - have a look at https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0 and https://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames to see how different each can be (example: [`ETCO`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59586097/4299358)).

*(Everything in this answer that has a bottom line is a link - not only the blue text.)*